# How to resolve connection refused when hit a sms api url in curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am sending an sms when create a new entry . I am using curl to hit the url . But in response i get "Failed connect to login.bulksmsrocket.com:8080; Connection refused".

```php
public function send_sms($mobile,$message){
    $email="xxxx@xxxx.com";

    $sender ='Health';
    $serverUrl="login.bulksmsrocket.com";
    $authkey="xxxxx&message";
    $route="1";
    $getData='mobileNos='.$mobile.'&message='.urlencode($message).'&senderId='.$sender.'&routeId='.$route;
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url="http://login.bulksmsrocket.com/rest/services/sendSMS/sendGroupSms?AUTH_KEY=".$authkey."&".$getData;


    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Cache-Control: no-cache"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        return $err;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

"Failed connect to login.bulksmsrocket.com:8080; Connection refused"

Comment: Check you're using the correct URL.

Comment: Yes i am using a correct url. When i am hit this url direct in browser then it is working and i get the message.

Comment: Really? I get 'Connection refused' on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

The url doesn't seem to work when you go to port 8080. Remove this line:

```
CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",
```

Comment: I Removed CURL_PORT => "8080" . It is working now but it showing resonse message empty with response code 3043. Do you know about this problem.

Comment: @JogenderDelaine No clue. 3043 is not a valid http response code. Plus there's no error message. You'll need to refer to whatever developer documentation they have, or contact their support directly. Also, if you have another question, you should ask a new question here on StackOverflow, so that you'll get a much better reach and it can be answered properly.

Comment: wtf, the only valid argument for CURLOPT_PORT is an int in the range of 0-65535 (inclusive), strings are not allowed. bet you didn't check the return value of curl_setopt()  (it returns bool(false) if it fails to set an option, and it should fail to set CURLOPT_PORT to a string.)